# Using ExtractData in ArcGIS API for Javascript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, error-000735

I cannot find any sample using ExtractData API.

I am trying to extract data from hosted feature layers using ExtractData JS API (not widget). The job that I submit fail with  the following message.

> Error: [{"type":"esriJobMessageTypeError","description":"ERROR 000735:
>   inputLayers: Value is
>   required"},{"type":"esriJobMessageTypeError","description":"Failed."}]

Following is part of the request.  The 'instance' object has root url and credentials. All layers are accessible and also I had made them public for testing purpose. I have spend lot of time trying to resolve this issue. There is no other meaningful information coming out of GP Service.

```
const job = await instance.get('/submitJob', {
        params: {
          inputLayers: [
             { url: soilURL, serviceToken: user.creds.token },
             { url: forestURL, serviceToken: user.creds.token },
             { url: homesiteURL, serviceToken: user.creds.token},
          ],

          extent: {
            url: parcelURL, 
            serviceToken: user.creds.token,
            filter: parcelFilter,
          },
          clip: true,
          dataFormat: 'FILEGEODATABASE ',
          outSR: 102100,
          outputName: {
            title: 'ACT 319 clip data',
            tag: 'clip data',
            snippet: 'clip data',
            description:
              'Clip and download soil type, home site and forest layers.',
          },
        },
      });
```

Comment: I know it sounds extreme, but most of ESRI's doc uses double quotes for attribute names. Try replacing `url: soilURL` with `"url": soilURL`etc. based on https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/extract-data.htm

Comment: @NettaB Thank you for your response. We were able to finally resolve the issue by using JSON.stringify to convert the parameter to string ```inputLayers: JSON.stringify([
          { url: soilURL, serviceToken: user.creds.token },
        ]),```

Comment: That's awesome, please add your solution as an answer - for future generations :)

Answer (score 2):

We resolved the issue by `JSON.stringfy()` the parameter. `inputLayers: JSON.stringify([ { url: soilURL, serviceToken: user.creds.token }, ]),`

Comment: You can mark this as "answered" to help others in the future.